# CSS distorted on browser back

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular app using TS with multiple components. Each of the component has their own CSS with encapsulation as none.

```
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-comp1',  
  templateUrl: './component1.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./component1.css'],  
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None  
})
```

The issue here is, if user hits browser back from component2 to component1, the resulting html includes the css of both the components and thus distorting component1.

How do i keep the css clean on browser back.

Comment: Is there any reason to avoid using `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` option?

Comment: If i am not mistaken that is the default one anyways though tried that too in both the components however, in that case component 2 is inheriting the component 1 styles. for e.g. i need different body backgrounds for different components